# Setting Gradient Background on UIView in Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionViewCell` which contains a `UIView` on which I want to set a gradient background. This is my `cellForItemAt` method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell: PaymentMethodCVCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "paymentMethodCVCell", for: indexPath) as? PaymentMethodCVCell {
           let row = indexPath.row
           cell.rewardsCard.setGradientBackground(colorTop: appRed, colorBottom: appRed.darkerColor(), withCornerRadius: 10)
           return cell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

where `setGradientBackground` is defined as an extension to `UIView`:

```
func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor, withCornerRadius : CGFloat){
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorBottom.cgColor, colorTop.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.cornerRadius = withCornerRadius
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

This works fine, but only when I scroll up and down in the `UICollectionView` and the cells are reloaded - the cells which are initially loaded onto the page don't have the background correctly set. Doing this in the `UICollectionViewCell` itself doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view `bounds` isn't yet to be known inside `cellForRowAt` plus it'll add many gradients when you scroll as cells are dequeued

```
gradientLayer.frame = bounds
```

So inside cell

```
var once = true

override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
    if once {
        // add gradient
        once = false
    }
 }
```

OR

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
    if !(rewardsCard.layer.sublayers?.first is CAGradientLayer ) {
        // add gradient 
    }
 }
```

Comment: how would I fix this issue?